# SSIS: How to read flatfile and add a new row to the file

Tags: ssis, row, addition, flat-file

I have a text file and needs to read it and change some text and add some new text in a new row.
How do I add e new row with some text in it?
I now use a script component to read existing rows and change in them but I can't add a new row :-(

Thanks in advance

Regards Brno

Answer (score 1):

To add rows, you need to change the script transfrom to asynchronous mode.

Look for "Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component" on MSDN.

(Currently the following link works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx)